# Habilitar domínio temporário /~USER/

Tags: cpanel, whm

Bom dia,
Não sei descrever bem, mas gostaria de habilitar "dominio temporário" vou chamar assim para tentar me expressar.

QUando crio um dominio no whm, sei que é possivel ver o iste assim:

http://IP-DO-SERVER/**~USUARIO**/

Fazendo as configurações do CSF, acabei desativando e eu preciso disso ativo. Alguem sabe como reativar?

Obrigado.

Comment: O nome correto é página de usuário

Answer (score -1):

Para que tiver o mesmo problema, segue solução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]